# bootbox custom dialog with both radio and select inputs

Tags: javascript, bootbox

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to place a `select` input on the right of a `radio` input in a custom `bootbox` dialog. Example:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a set of radio inputs!",
    message: '<p>Please select an option below:</p>',
    inputType: 'radio',
    inputOptions: [
    {
        text: 'Choice One',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Two',
        value: '2',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Three',
        value: '3',
    }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

This will show three radio items.
I want to place on the right of, say, 'Choice Two' a `select`:

```
inputType: 'select',
inputOptions: [
{
    text: 'Choose one...',
    value: '',
},
{
    text: 'Choice One',
    value: '1',
}]
```

But I don't understand if this is possible with `bootbox`.

Comment: Not with the `bootbox.prompt` helper, no. You can create your own custom dialogs, using `bootbox.dialog({ /* your options here */ })`. http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#custom-dialog

Comment: @TiesonT., even with `bootbox.custom` I don't understand how to put custom `html` tags. I have to put everything inside the `message` field?

Comment: Yes. You would create a normal form, with all the input and labels you would display if it was rendered inside a normal page, and then load that into the message option of the dialog. You would then need to setup your buttons, using the `buttons` option, and handle getting the selected values inside the callback of whatever button is your "submit" button. If you can come up with the markup for a rough version of what you're trying to do, I can add an answer showing how to integrate that. Otherwise, you'd have to wait until I have time to write all of that myself, or someone else answers.

Comment: @TiesonT. thanks for your time. I changed the program flow and now when the user select a radio button I redirect it to a normal form (I discovered I need more than just a select). Anyway, I understood how to do it in the future.